# Failure to find module in split namespace

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I am working with `Python 3.3.1` 64 bit on `Ubuntu 13.04` 64 bit running under `Eclipse 4.3` 64 bit with `Pydev 2.7.6` in a `virtualenv` environment. I have my project in the following directory structure.

```
Dictionary
     |
     ----------------------------
     |                          |
     src                        test
       |                          |
       petaapan                   petaapan
          |   |                   |      |
__init__.py logging        __init__.py  logging
            |     |                     |     |
   __init__.py    mplogging.py  __init__.py  test_mplogging.py
```

When I try to run `test_mplogging.py` using `pytest` as the test runner I get the following results:

```
pydev debugger: starting
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.3.1 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: pep8, cache
collected 0 items / 1 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting test_mplogging.py ______________________
File "/home/jonathan/UC/Git Repositories/isiiwesuu/Dictionary/tests/petaapan/logging/test_mplogging.py", line 11
in <module>
>   import petaapan.logging.mplogging as ml
E   ImportError: No module named 'petaapan.logging.mplogging'
```

My `sys.path` has `Dictionary/test` ahead of `Dictionary/src` so the test tree is searched first and it looks as though that is why the import failed with regular packages.

My next attempt was to do the same using namespace packages, so I removed all the `__init__.py` files and got the following results:

```
pydev debugger: starting
============================= test session starts ==============================
platform linux -- Python 3.3.1 -- pytest-2.3.5
plugins: pep8, cache
collected 0 items / 1 errors

==================================== ERRORS ====================================
______________________ ERROR collecting test_mplogging.py ______________________
File "/home/jonathan/UC/Git Repositories/isiiwesuu/Dictionary/tests/petaapan/logging/test_mplogging.py", line 11
in <module>
>   import petaapan.logging.mplogging as ml
File "/home/jonathan/UC/Git Repositories/isiiwesuu/Dictionary/tests/petaapan/logging/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1564
in _find_and_load
>   ???
File "/home/jonathan/UC/Git Repositories/isiiwesuu/Dictionary/tests/petaapan/logging/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1522
in _find_and_load_unlocked
>   ???
File "/home/jonathan/UC/Git Repositories/isiiwesuu/Dictionary/tests/petaapan/logging/<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1476
in _find_module
>   ???
File "/home/jonathan/isiiwesuu/lib/python3.3/site-packages/_pytest/assertion/rewrite.py", line 68
in find_module
>               fd, fn, desc = imp.find_module(lastname, path)
File "/home/jonathan/isiiwesuu/lib/python3.3/imp.py", line 197
in find_module
>                              "not {}".format(type(name)))
E           RuntimeError: 'list' must be None or a list, not <class 'str'>
=========================== 1 error in 0.49 seconds ============================
```

Here is `test_mplogging.py` relevant parts:

```
import logging
from os import getcwd

from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
import petaapan.logging.mplogging as ml
```

Can anyone suggest what I need to do in this situation?

Comment: I have been investigating this problem further. It is beginning to look like there is a potential problem in `pytest` with split namespaces, The support for PEP420 introduced a new internal class `_NamespacePath` and `pytest` hooks the import machinery to allow it to rewrite asssertions. The problem is that the `pytest rewrite` module does not understand this new class and eventually causes the import to fail. I am investigating further and will report my findings in an Answer.

Comment: I am hoping that someone from the `pytest` dev team will comment on this so I can take it further.

Answer (score 1):

As I can see you have `petaapan.logging.mplogging` under `Dictionary/src`, but not under `Dictionary/test`.

I believe the interpreter parses `petaapan` from the `import` instruction and finds it out in `Dictionary/test` and then suggests that it is the module you refer to. But after that it cannot find `mplogging` in `Dictionary/test/petaapan/logging` (in the scope of detected module) and thus throws an exception.

Comment: That was true prior to Python 3.3 which added support for split name-spaces. Under Python 3.3.1 and 3.3.2 that directory structure works just fine. That is what split name-spaces are for after all. The problem is that Pydev does not yet support split name-spaces.